# Magnetic field due to electron in Hydrogen?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

We can calculate the current density $\mathbf{j}$ of the electron in Hydrogen, and it is given by:
$$
j_\phi=-e\frac{\hbar m}{\mu r\sin\theta}\left|\psi_{nlm}\left(r,\theta,\phi\right)\right|^2
$$
([derivation found here](http://www.phys.spbu.ru/content/File/Library/studentlectures/schlippe/qm07-05.pdf) on page 6)

How can I calculate the magnetic field produced by this current density?

I could use the Biot-Savart law, 
$$d\textbf{B}  = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \frac{1}{r^2} \int Id\textbf{s}$$
where the integration should be (at least classicaly) the along the current loop, and $I$ = $\int \textbf{J} \cdot d\textbf{S}$. What should I use as $d\textbf{S}$ and $d\textbf{s}$ for an electron in Hydrogen?

Comment: Don't you want to use a volumetric form of Biot-Savart instead since your current doesn't resemble a wire?

Comment: The internal field should be ~0.4 tesla, http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydfin.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I think it is explained fairly well in these lecture notes that you linked. Since the current j only has a φ component, you have to integrate over circles like the ones shown in the figure. These circles have a fixed radius and θ coordinate. Only φ varies.

[image]

The radius of that circle is $r \sin\theta$ and therefore $ds=r \sin\theta d\phi$.
You should now be able to calculate $dB$. To calculate the total magnetic field then, if you wish to do so, you will have to integrate dB over all $r$ and $\theta$.

Hope this helps!